# I am unable to download gem5 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gem5

```
sudo apt-get install swig gcc m4 python python-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev mercurial scons g++ build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python

E: Unable to locate package swig
E: Unable to locate package m4
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libgoogle-perftools-dev
E: Unable to locate package mercurial
E: Unable to locate package scons
```

I even tried sudo-apt get update before trying this command but it gives the same result

Comment: the problem was because of some proxy settings at my university. It was resolved after fixing that